# after web filter all images gone in jsf page

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security, servlet-filters

I am using spring security with jsf 2. I have a filter that control if db access is ok in each page. :

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest aReq, ServletResponse aResponse, FilterChain aChain) throws IOException,
        ServletException
{

    ...
    if(!myContext.isdbRunning())
    {
        mLogger.debug("System not working. Redirecting to: "+"/error.jsf");
        aReq.setAttribute("errorMsj", "DB is not started. Please contact DB admin.");
        aReq.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsf").forward(aReq, aResponse);
        return;
    }

    aChain.doFilter(aReq, aResponse);
    return; 
}
```

If everything is ok, my jsf page is rendered correctly. but when filter finds a problem in db, it processes to an error page.

```
aReq.getRequestDispatcher("/error.jsf").forward(aReq, aResponse);
```

but that page dosn't show images and other css based stuff..

does spring security take control and disallow my page contents? or do I have a mistake? How can I solve it? Can I use Phase listener?

Edit: part of my web.xml is

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>Gatekeeper</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.jsfsample.filter.GateKeeperFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

   <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Gatekeeper</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>


  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: How do you exclude images from being handled by the filter?

Comment: post your security context configuration please.

Comment: hi, thanks for your responses, I edited and added my web.xml, i hope i didnt misunderstand you. Also, is it possible that web contents are not found because of path problem?

Comment: thanks for the update, but I need your applicationSecurity.xml or however you have named it. The file where you define your <intercept-url> elements, your <http entry-point-ref>, <form-login> etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are your css/scripts/images loaded with a separate request ?

If so make sure their url (http://domain.com/styles.css) is not secured.

---

A bit more detail on unsecuring specific URLs.

In your security context config file you should have something like:

```
<http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
    <intercept-url pattern="/something/relativeUrlThatLoadsImages.jsf" filters="none" />

    <!-- OR -->    

    <intercept-url pattern="/something/relativeUrlThatLoadsImages.jsf" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
</http>
```

Either `filters="none"` or `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"` will unsecure the relative URL specified in the `pattern` attribute.

I personally prefer using `filters="none"`, because it tells spring not to load the filter chain at all for these URLs.

This way you won't need to code to make spring ignore these URLs and you will have a place to change access to them easily in the future if you need to.

Comment: hi Simeon, they are loaded with separate request, and pattern ends with .jsf extension also.( like : xx.css.jsf)

Comment: @asyard in that case make sure the url for the request is not secured by spring security, if it is than this is most likely the problem.

Comment: Simeon, thank you. I modified my filter, if request.getservletcontext.contains(".css.jsf") or ("jpg.jsf") then I dochain it, otherwise I forward to error page: solved my problem. Is is a bad idea? If so, can you give me a bit more detail? Why css and jpg files end with .jsf ?

Comment: well the only thing that worries me this way is that if you try to secure these URLs in the future from the config you won't be able to because of the code, but if you're not worried about that than this is ok, I'll edit my answer with a bit more detail

Comment: you are right Simeon, I will consider your suggestion, thank you for your help.